# find which strings are the same between rows of two columns with different length

Tags: r

```
a <- data.frame(name = c("Abe Lyu", "Abe Lyu", "Lefebvre Arnaud", rep("De Dinechin Florent", 3)))
b <- data.frame(name = c(rep ("Lefebvre Arnaud", 4)))
```

I would like to use something like this to compare columns from two different dataframes. The problem is that the two dataframes have different lengths. How can I compare them?

```
a$name == b$name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they need to be data.frames you can use the `semi_join` in the `dplyr` package. If you want get the filter `a` data frame based on the `name` column with the `name` column in `b`. I added row ids just to show the indexes for each data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

a <- data.frame(name = c("Abe Lyu", "Abe Lyu", "Lefebvre Arnaud", rep("De Dinechin Florent", 3)))
b <- data.frame(name = c(rep ("Lefebvre Arnaud", 4)))

a <- tibble::rowid_to_column(a, var = "rowid_a")
b <- tibble::rowid_to_column(b, var = "rowid_b")

semi_join(a, b, by = "name")

#  rowid_a            name
#1       3 Lefebvre Arnaud
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
a %>% 
  filter(name %in% b$name)
```